# Modify render settings for all scenes using python

Tags: python, scene

I have some basic render settings (border off, resolution, etc.) that I would like to have applied for **all** scenes in the .blend file using Python, via the `-P` **command line** switch.

I have tried:

```
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
```

but it only operates on the active scene.

Comment: Operators usually operate on the active scene, if you iterate over `bpy.data.scenes` however, it will give you all scenes in the .blend. The active scene can be determined via `bpy.context.scene`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works fine for me.

```
import bpy

for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    scene.render.resolution_x = 1920
    scene.render.resolution_y = 1080
    scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100
    scene.render.use_border = False
```

Placing this in a file (`test.py`) and running blender with

```
blender test.blend -P test.py
```

Opens blender with all the settings set to the values defined in the Python script, in both scenes.

Comment: Yes it works, classic user error, after adding the for loop I forgot to change "bpy.context.scene." to "scene." so it only got called on the current scene (for a couple of times :-)