# Can you link render settings across all scenes so they can all be changed at once?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, linked-data, render-layers, scene

I have multiple scenes to render and in my "master" scene I have set up the render nodes to output the render of all scenes. This way I only have to hit the Render Animation button once and all of the scenes get output.

The problem is that I still have to manually change the render settings of each scene to match.

Is there a way to sync / link the render settings of each scene so that I only need to change them once?

More detail if it's not clear: If I want to render a preview, I have to manually set each scene to my "Preview" settings, but then when I am render for the final render I will have to once again manually change ALL of the scenes render settings to my desired high quality.
Also, I am using Cycles.

Comment: I have also tried and looks like you can't apply drivers or expressions to all of the settings to link them back to the master scene.

Comment: You may want to try Python approach. Here's a similar case described:
[Modify render settings for all scenes using python](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9164/modfiy-render-settings-for-all-scenes-using-python)

Comment: There is a copy render settings add-on that comes with blender.