# Copy render settings between scenes using Python

Tags: python

I simply want to take the render settings from one scene and copy them to another scene. Something like

```
bpy.data.scenes[1].render = bpy.data.scenes[0].render
```

except that this fails as `bpy.types.Scene.render` is read-only. Ideally I'd like the render settings linked between the scenes but I'll settle for deep-copying.

I previously found [Can you link render settings across all scenes so they can all be changed at once?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62769/can-you-link-render-settings-across-all-scenes-so-they-can-all-be-changed-at-onc) but it doesn't get an answer.

The only solution I can come up with is manually copying each and every attribute one at a time but this seems very cumbersome. I also found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818825/python-what-is-the-correct-way-to-copy-an-objects-attributes-over-to-another/3818861#3818861 which gets me some of the way but falls over for read-only attributes, i.e. the other classes within `bpy.types.Scene.render`.

Any help much appreciated as this appears simple to do! Thanks.

Comment: Is there a better solution without any add-on now in Blender 3.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this bundled addon for this:

[image]

If you specifically need the python code, you can do it like this:

```
import bpy
settings = ["resolution_x", "resolution_y", "resolution_percentage"]
dict = {sett: getattr(bpy.context.scene.render, sett) for sett in settings}
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    for sett, val in dict.items():
        setattr(scene.render, sett, val)
```